# Stream VOD from remote server using Azure media services

Tags: azure-media-services

We would like to use Azure media services to stream the VODs that are currently available in the data center. We do not like to store these VOD files in blob storage rather in our own data center. These VODs are accessible through an URL from the data center.

Kindly let us know whether it is possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I'm sorry to say that this is not a supported scenario.  The files are required to be stored in an Azure Storage account in a folder that Media Services Packager and Origin (Streaming Endpoint) can access.  The Packager is not able to reach out across the internet (via VPN) to another on-premises storage repository and deliver the content.

I'd like more details on the business reason why you are not able to put the streaming VOD files on Azure vs. your data center. That would be good feedback for us to hear if we were to consider this as a future feature.